# Java 8 compiler Plugin : How to add extending expression to a generated class?

Tags: java, javac, annotation-processing

I'm writing a Java compiler plugin to add a simple class named `MyClass` in some classes of my project (something like lombok does). I've managed to do it by writing the code bellow (you can find the overall code is [here](https://gist.github.com/mcherb/6eed3e8f7919fa31beced33b8a54d297)):

```java
TreeMaker maker = TreeMaker.instance(context);
Names symbolsTable = Names.instance(context);

JCTree.JCClassDecl myClass = maker
        .at(((JCTree) node).pos)
        .ClassDef(maker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC | Flags.STATIC | Flags.FINAL),
                symbolsTable.fromString("MyClass"),
                List.nil(),
                null, // replace Here by ?
                List.nil(),
                List.nil()
        );

((JCTree.JCClassDecl) node).defs = ((JCTree.JCClassDecl) node).defs.append(myClass);
```

The code before will generate :

```java
public static class MyClass {
}
```

Now, I want `MyClass` to extend another parametrized class :

```java
public static class MyClass extends AnotherClass<Param1, Param2>{
}
```

I don't know how to do it !
All I know it is to change the 4th parameter of the `ClassDef` method from `null` to a `JCExpression`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extends expression :

```java
JCTree.JCIdent extendClassName = maker.Ident(symbolsTable.fromString("AnotherClass"));

ListBuffer<JCTree.JCExpression> extendsParams = new ListBuffer<>();
extendsParams.add(maker.Ident(symbolsTable.fromString("Param1")));
extendsParams.add(maker.Ident(symbolsTable.fromString("Param2")));

JCTree.JCTypeApply extend = maker.TypeApply(extendClassName, extendsParams.toList());
```

The best documentation I've found is the [lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/20cce2049de56d5a71c6dcc376d6f4088d4552bc/src/core/lombok/javac/handlers/HandleSuperBuilder.java#L421) project